# Escaping a quote in Prolog

Tags: prolog, escaping

I want to pass an apostrophe (`'`) symbol as an argument to the predicate `write/1`, like this:

```
write(''')
```

but obviously it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this? Like `write('\'')` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, `write('\'').` will work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

```
\\, \', \", \`
Stand for the character following the `\'.
```

(per http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.12.7/html/sicstus/Escape-Sequences.html)